# Google Assistant Hotword Detection Not Working

Tags: raspberry-pi3, grpc, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I'm new to Google Assistant SDK. Recently I embedded Assistant to Raspberry Pi 3 B. I used the **googlesamples-assistant-hotword** sample. It worked fine. But next time I run the command I got some errors. I reinstall the sdk and tried, but got the same error. However **googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk** still works. But **googlesamples-assistant-hotword** gives errors. How can I fix this. The errors I got are as follows;

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~$ googlesamples-assistant-hotword
ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
  {u'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED
E0922 08:01:19.189206804    9868 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1506047479.189164282","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1506047479.189160249","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":1045}]}
E0922 08:01:20.189959242    9868 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1506047480.189916251","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1506047480.189911706","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":1045}]}
E0922 08:01:21.190931499    9868 handshake.c:128]            Security handshake failed: {"created":"@1506047481.190904069","description":"Handshake read failed","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/security/transport/handshake.c","file_line":237,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1506047481.190900454","description":"FD shutdown","file":"../../third_party/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/ev_epoll_linux.c","file_line":1045}]}
[9782:9800:ERROR:speech_recognition_activity.cc(550)] S3 connection has timed out: No data from S3
```

Comment: Alfonso from the Assistant SDK team here. We believe this is an issue that occurs with slow or spotty connections, and we will try to fix it in a future release. Can you check on a better network and confirm if this still happens every time?

Comment: Hi Alfonso. I too had the same issue and and when I changed the network, it works fine.